# How to extract a block from a big matrix?

Tags: matrix

Given a square matrix $A_{n\times n}$ how can one extract a square block matrix $B_{m \times m}$ from it? As an example, from the following $8\times 8$ matrix, how to define a matrix $B$ which is the top-right $4\times 4$ block of matrix $A$?

```
 A={{a11 ,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18},
    {a21,a22,a23,a24,a25,a26,a27,a28},
    {a31,a32,a33,a34,a35,a36,a37,a38},
    {a41,a42,a43,a44,a45,a46,a47,a48},
    {a51,a52,a53,a54,a55,a56,a57,a58},
    {a61,a62,a63,a64,a65,a66,a67,a68},
    {a71,a72,a73,a74,a75,a76,a77,a78},
    {a81,a82,a83,a84,a85,a86,a87,a88}};
```

Comment: `B = A[[1 ;; 4, -4 ;; -1]]` or `Take[A, 4, -4]`?

Comment: Another way to do it: `A[[Range[4], Range[4]]]`

Comment: Thanks @SjoerdSmit, that works for me!